# How to run *.pt file trained using OpenNMT-py in a different Python script?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, nlp, opennmt

I have trained `Hindi-English` parallel language corpora using `OpenNMT-py`, after running to some epoch I got checkpoints as `10k.pt`, `5k.pt`, etc.

Now I want to use that `.pt` file in a different Python script.

How to do it?

Following are my configurations:

- `OpenNMT-py = 3.4.3`
- `Python = 3.10.13`
- `torch = 2.1.2+cpu`